# Altium Designer - How to make chamfer on 90 degrees tracks?

Tags: altium, routing

My need, is what you can read in the title: how can I make chamfer in 90° tracks connections? I've found a way to do that but works only with auto-routing. I want to do it manually.

I have Altium Designer 10 and i don't understand how to do it in a simple way.

Currently:

[image: original routing]

What I want to achieve:

[image: what i need]

Comment: Take a look at this link: [Convert Tracks to Chamfered Path](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Dlg-ConvertTracksToChamferedPath((Convert+Tracks+to+Chamfered+Path))_AD)(I'm not sure it applies to your version of Altium). Alternatively, you can just drag the 90 degree corner inwards, to make a chamfer

Comment: Yes, i've already tried that but in my version of altium is not possible. For the aother suggestion....how can i drag a corner?...i'm able only to drag traks. thank you

Comment: Just drag the end of any of the two tracks that form the 90 degree angle. When you get to the corner, the cursor should change to an double-ended arrow and then you can drag a chamfer (I'm talking from memory, I might be wrong about the specifics; but if you want to do what I think you want to do, it's extremely simple! why don't you post a picture, so there's no misunderstanding)

Comment: I update my post with pics. I tried to follow your guide but i can't be able to create chamfer.

Comment: I thought you wanted something like this: http://techdocs.altium.com/sites/default/files/wiki_attachments/235811/Dialog_ConvertToChamfered.png

Comment: In Altium Designer V10 this is what i can configure about teardrop option. Track and T-junction are not present :( [![Teardrop Option in Altium 10](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h8iWV.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h8iWV.png) I'm afraid there's no way to do what i need.

Comment: Why don't you update your version of Altium? If you obtained it legitimately you should have full access to Altiulm 15.1. If you pirated it, this is one of the reasons why I don't promote cracked software--You lose access to important and useful updates.

Comment: The update from AD10 to AD15 is not free...if i remeber right it cost about 5.000€...so this is why i continue to use AD10 for wich we paid to get the licence.  I would like to post as a comment, but comment form doesn't have quick commands to upload pic :)

Comment: Altium upgrades are only available with a subscription. Otherwise you are buying out a brand new copy of altium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I don't add chamfers manually. I use the "Teardrop" feature (found under Tools > Teardrops, or shortcut T-E):

[image]
[image]

Using the above settings, this is what I get on a T-junction:
[image]

It also works on pads (through-hole AND SMD):
[image]

Using teardrops really helps improve the look of your layout, and avoids any sharp angles that could cause issues during manufacturing. In the Teardrops dialog, in the Options pane, you could set the "Teardrop style" to "Line" instead of "Curved" to get the exact chamfer you ask about:

[image]

---

EDIT: This is based on the assumption that you are running Altium version 14.3 or higher. Before that, the Teardrops menu was different and did not have support for T-junction teardrops. In that case, instead of using a regular T-junction, I would recommend a connection like this:

[image]

If you really want a filled chamfer, you can draw the above with the traces, then place a triangular solid region in the empty area:

[image]

This ends up looking like this:

[image]

Comment: Great I though that teardrop was only for pad! Thank you very much ;)

Comment: I'm afraid that with altium V10 doesn't work :( Thank's anyway.

Comment: @GianlucaSuzzi please see my edit.

Comment: Yes..infact in the end i did like your second suggestion..i put a triangle over the junction. Thank you for the support!